# How to implement ComponentScan's CUSTOM Filter using lambda?

Tags: java, spring, lambda

When using `@ComponentScan` with a custom filter, the code should look like this:

```
@ComponentScan(includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(
type = FilterType.CUSTOM, value = {**TypeFilterImpl**.class})})
```

But when looking at `TypeFilter`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TypeFilter {
    boolean match(MetadataReader var1, MetadataReaderFactory var2) throws IOException;
}
```

As is told by the `@FunctionalInterface`, it seems a perfect situation to use lambda. But then we have this:

```
@interface Filter {
    Class<?>[] value() default {};
}
```

Which means the `@ComponentScan.@Filter.value` only accepts `Class<?>[]`, not the typical `@FunctionalInterface` annotated class for lambda.

So is it possible to use lambda if the required argument is `Class`? If not, how would you update this `Filter` class to support it?

Comment: why not use `TypeFilter.class` there itself?

Comment: @Naman, I don't get it, isn't it supposed to be implemented before using?

Comment: To what I could infer the `value` accepts an arrray of `Class` and not instances. So it would be either all the `**Implementation.class` in an array or the `**Interface.class` in that array. But `.class` and not their instance. With lambda, you end up defining a class instead of referencing them as one.( by `Name.class` for e.g.)

Comment: @Naman, yes I understand that lambda can be treated as a lightweight replacement of anonymous class instance, and the value requires an array of `Class`. I just wanna know if there's a way to use lambda here, since the `@FunctionalInterface` seems a guiding light, telling me "you should use lambda here!"